# How to display images with CSS, and a certain percantage of the image cut out

Tags: images, html, css

Assume that the original picture is 500px in height and 400 px in width. I want to display this picture in website such that only 480px in visible in height. Is this possible using css?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your image as background to a div/span and change size of div/span to your desired size